# How can I add embed animated gif to a github repository README.md?

Tags: github, repository, animated-gif

The animated gif I have is 2.5MB size
Converted it from mp4 video.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see an animated gif in this [`kellim/farmers-market-finder` README file](https://github.com/kellim/farmers-market-finder).

The [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kellim/farmers-market-finder/master/README.md) shows that gif embedded as any other picture:

```
![Farmers Market Finder - Animated gif demo](demo/demo.gif)
```

You have the same method used in "[How to add GIFs to your GitHub README](https://medium.com/@josephcardillo/how-to-add-gifs-to-your-github-readme-89c74da2ce47)" from [Joe Cardillo](https://github.com/josephcardillo).

Answer (score 1):

Simply upload gif in the root folder of your repository and add below line in Readme.md file

```
![Alt text](name_of_your_gif_file.gif)
```

Push your code and it will work like magic